# How to get the minimum of one column and get another column without grouping?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a record from a table that has the minimum value of a specific column, but I want the rest of the data in that record without grouping one of the columns.

This is sample data:

[image: sample date]

I want a query that will return:

> January, 24, 0, 3
> February, 12, 0, 1

Comment: Minimum of _which_ column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use analytic function which "ranks" data; then fetch rows that rank as the *highest*. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (month, day, c_initial, ending) as
  2    (select 'jan', 24, 0, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 'jan', 24, 1, 6 from dual union all
  4     select 'jan', 24, 2, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 'feb', 12, 0, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 'feb', 12, 1, 6 from dual union all
  7     select 'feb', 12, 2, 5 from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select t.*,
 11       row_number() over (partition by month, day order by c_initial) rn
 12     from test t
 13    )
 14  select month, day, c_initial, ending
 15  from temp
 16  where rn = 1;

MON        DAY  C_INITIAL     ENDING
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
feb         12          0          1
jan         24          0          3

SQL>
```

---

If there are *ties*, then consider `RANK` instead.

Also, `initial` is invalid column name so I renamed it to `c_initial`.

Answer (score 2):

@Littlefoot gave probably the only reasonable answer.  However, if your table is very large and performance is an issue, this version might be more efficient:

```
select    month, 
          day, 
          min(c_initial) keep ( dense_rank first order by c_initial asc ) c_initial,
          min(ending) keep ( dense_rank first order by c_initial asc ) ending
from      your_table
group by  month, day;
```

The `min() keep` tells Oracle you just want the value for which ever row in each group has the lowest value for `c_initial`.  So, it can discard the values it knows you're not interested in, rather than keeping them around, sorting them, and then giving you the first one.

*Incidentally, what tells Oracle to return the data for the row having this lowest `c_initial` value is the `dense_rank first order by c_initial asc` clause and NOT the `min()` function.  Using a `max()` function would give the exact same answer.  I use `min()` is just a style thing -- it reminds me that I'm looking for the first row in the group.*